# Running "tsc" is checking one file in "node_modules"

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript

When running `tsc` on a react-native project, I'm getting a type error in one of the node_modules libraries:

```
node_modules/react-native-swiper-flatlist/src/components/SwiperFlatList/SwiperFlatList.tsx:79:17 - error TS7031: Binding element '_index' implicitly has an 'any' type.

79       ({ index: _index, prevIndex: _prevIndex }) => {
```

`tsc` shouldn't be checking node_modules, as it's explicetely ignored in the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "include": ["src", "storybook", "types"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js"],

  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I saw a related post on ignoring node_modules, and it suggested adding     `"skipLibCheck": true` to the tsconfig.json, but that didn't change anything.

I'm importing `react-native-swiper-flatlist` in one place the following way:

```
import { SwiperFlatList } from "react-native-swiper-flatlist";
```

Using typescript v4.7.3.

Any idea why `tsc` would be picking up this one specific file, and any suggestions on how to exclude it from being checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs for exclude, [it doesn't guarantee that the files will be excluded, it just changes the discovery search pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude). If you include the files via import into your main codebase, the files will still be included.

If you want to use that file, you will just need to [turn off the implicit any check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) via the tsconfig flag:

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "include": ["src", "storybook", "types"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js"],

  "compilerOptions": {
       //... your other options
       "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also ignore it with a comment in the library code and use patch-package to update it.

Comment: Yea unfortunately this seems to be an issue in Typescript -https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40426.

Comment: We've submitted a PR to the library with this issue hoping they'll merge it and release a new version soon.